# Ошибка при инициализации свойства класса функцией

Tags: php

Когда пробую в ооп перевести запрос к базе данных, то выдает ошибку синтаксис эррор.....

```
protected $queryShopMenu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu_item WHERE option_id='$option'");
```

Comment: Телепаты из нашего боевого отряда уже пытаются выяснить, какую именно ошибку вам выдает интерпертатор, ждите.

Comment: в присвоении свойствам значений можно использовать mysql_query??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Телепаты сообразили: в классе нельзя задавать начальные значения свойств функциями.

```
protected $a = false; // норм
protected $b; // тоже норм
protected $c = func(); // а так нельзя
```

ваша задачка может быть решена так:

```
protected $c;
public function __construct() {
    $this->c = mysql_query(...);
}
```

Comment: спасиб... токо вникаю... ;))